# Independence for subsets of [0,1]

Tags: probability, independence, uniform-distribution

I'm struggling with this problem:

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the uniform measure on $[0,1].$ Define $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$ with $a<c.$ State the necessary and sufficient conditions for $A$ and $B$ to be independent.

What I've done so far is drawn some intervals

[image: Drawn Intervals]

From the definition of independence I require that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B).$ A sufficient condition is that $A \cap B = \varnothing.$ Where I'm getting confused is how to handle non-disjoint sets. I feel like they should be dependent, but another part of me feels like I'm not on the right track. Unless I'm totally off base.

EDIT: After reading the comments I realize that $A \cap B = \varnothing$ is not a sufficient condition. I left it in my initial asking in case others thought the same.

Comment: You are on the right track: the next step is just expressing $P(A \cap B)$ in terms of $a, b, c, d$ for all three plots you have drawn, then state $P(A \cap B) = (b - a)(d - c)$.

Comment: Do you mean the def of independence is $\mathbb{P}(A \cup  B) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$? Rather than $\mathbb{P}(A \cap  B) $? Thatis obviously wrong if you think it through.

Comment: If $A\cap B = \emptyset$, then $A$ and $B$ are _not_ independent in general because $P(A\cap  B)$ is typically nonzero whille $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are not. This makes it hard to assert (with a straight face) that the condition $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ holds and so $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Comment: Drawing pictures is good.  You should now be able to *see* that (except for edge cases) the second and third drawings exemplify non-independence, leaving you to analyze only the first drawing.  For that, apply the definition of independence to obtain an algebraic relation among $(a,b,c,d).$